# With RxJs in Angular do I need to only complete the Observables created in the component?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Basically I'm still not really sure about the cleanup of reactive code in Angular components. Are the following rules correct and sufficient?

My rules for a reactive component:

- on manual *x.subscribe()*:

  - if using *x.takeUntil(...)* or similar construct then no manual cleanup
  - if *x.complete()* is called in the component scope then no manual cleanup
  - else manual *.unsubscribe()* on demand or in *ngOnDestroy()*
- on template's *observable | async*:

  - no manual cleanup needed plus onPush compatible
- on manual direct creation of Observable like *new Subject()*:

  - manual *.complete()* in *ngOnDestroy()* else never closes
- on manual creation using other Observables like *Observable.merge(...)*:

  - no manual cleanup needed as long as subscription is cleaned up

I'm not really sure about the last bullet point.

Here is a full example of a real component I refactored according to those rules, can someone see whether there is danger for a memory leak? All public $ observables are subscribed via *async* pipe in the template so I'm sure that the subscriptions are taken care of. The subjects created with *new* are manually cleaned up so that should be OK. The parts I'm worried about are the *Observable.combineLatest(...)* observables.

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, Input, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { DeliveryPointId } from 'app/bso';
import { BookmarkService } from 'app/general';
import { EAccess, EPermission, ReduxGetters, ReduxService } from 'app/redux';
import * as routing from 'app/routing';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'app/rx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-last-opened-workitems-widget',
  templateUrl: './last-opened-workitems-widget.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class LastOpenedWorkitemsWidgetComponent implements OnDestroy {

  private readonly showPartners$ = new BehaviorSubject(true);
  private readonly showServices$ = new BehaviorSubject(true);
  private readonly showTens$ = new BehaviorSubject(true);
  private readonly showWorklist$ = new BehaviorSubject(true);

  @Input() set showItems(val: boolean) { this.showWorklist$.next(!!val); }
  @Input() set showPartners(val: boolean) { this.showPartners$.next(!!val); }
  @Input() set showProcesses(val: boolean) { this.showServices$.next(!!val); }
  @Input() set showTens(val: boolean) { this.showTens$.next(!!val); }

  constructor(
    private readonly redux: ReduxService,
    private readonly bookmarks: BookmarkService,
    private readonly router: Router,
  ) { }

  canPartners$ = this.redux.watch(ReduxGetters.userAccess).map(access => access[EPermission.Partner] >= EAccess.Read);
  canServices$ = this.redux.watch(ReduxGetters.userAccess).map(access => access[EPermission.Services] >= EAccess.Read);
  canTens$ = this.redux.watch(ReduxGetters.userAccess).map(access => access[EPermission.Tens] >= EAccess.Read);
  canWorklist$ = this.redux.watch(ReduxGetters.userAccess).map(access => access[EPermission.Worklist] >= EAccess.Read);

  lastItems$ = this.bookmarks.onLastOpenedWorkitems.map(ii => [...ii].reverse());
  lastPartners$ = this.bookmarks.onLastOpenedPartners.map(ii => [...ii].reverse());
  lastProcesses$ = this.bookmarks.onLastOpenedProcesses.map(ii => [...ii].reverse());
  lastTens$ = this.bookmarks.onLastOpenedTens.map(ii => [...ii].reverse());

  hasContentPartners$ = Observable
    .combineLatest(
      this.showPartners$.distinctUntilChanged(),
      this.canPartners$,
      this.lastPartners$.map(ii => ii.length > 0))
    .map(oks => oks.every(ii => ii));

  hasContentServices$ = Observable
    .combineLatest(
      this.showServices$.distinctUntilChanged(),
      this.canServices$,
      this.lastProcesses$.map(ii => ii.length > 0))
    .map(oks => oks.every(ii => ii));

  hasContentTens$ = Observable
    .combineLatest(
      this.showTens$.distinctUntilChanged(),
      this.canTens$,
      this.lastTens$.map(ii => ii.length > 0))
    .map(oks => oks.every(ii => ii));

  hasContentWorklist$ = Observable
    .combineLatest(
      this.showWorklist$.distinctUntilChanged(),
      this.canWorklist$,
      this.lastItems$.map(ii => ii.length > 0))
    .map(oks => oks.every(ii => ii));

  hasContent$ = Observable
    .combineLatest(this.hasContentPartners$, this.hasContentServices$, this.hasContentTens$, this.hasContentWorklist$)
    .map(oks => oks.some(ii => ii));

  ngOnDestroy() {
    [this.showPartners$, this.showServices$, this.showTens$, this.showWorklist$].forEach(ii => ii.complete());
  }

  gotoPartner = (id: string) => routing.gotoPartnerItem(this.router, id);
  gotoProcess = (id: number) => routing.gotoProcess(this.router, id);
  gotoTensItem = (id: DeliveryPointId) => routing.gotoTensItem(this.router, id);
  gotoWorkitem = (id: number) => routing.gotoWorkitem(this.router, id);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I actually just tested it with *.finally(...)* plus logging for all intermediate Observables and it gets fired properly when the component is destroyed.

Thus I declare the rules above correct und sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You need to unsubscribe each and every of your subscriptions, for example in the `ngOnDestroy()` method.

Or you may 'limit' the observables using operators such as `takeUntil()`, `take()`, `first()` etc.

The above rules are valid for `combineLatest` as well.

Do not worry about subscriptions created by `AsyncPipe` because `AsyncPipe` itself is responsible for unsubscribting for its own subscriptions.

A good read on this topic is the [article](https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-dont-unsubscribe-6753ed4fda87) by Ben Lesh who is the RxJS lead.

Comment: Thx, but that's basically what I already summed up above. Subscription cleanup isn't my problem here, but figuring out whether and when the Observables themselves need to be completed manually (i.e. calling *complete()*).